# how to find the bandwith of my ubuntu vm on azure?

Tags: azure, vps

I deployed a ubuntu server on azure VM to be acted like a VPS. But I couldn't find what's the bandwidth my vps can provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consult [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/sizes-general) page. Network bandwidth depends on the size of your VM.

just find your vm size and you will find the answer in the table